# Get the current session history only for Python interactive session?

Tags: python, session, python-interactive

This question is specific to using the `python -i` command (not `IPython`): how can I limit the exported history to commands from the current session only?

Specifically, when I run Python via terminal (`python -i`) and then type the following commands:

```py
from pathlib import Path
x = Path('abc')
from readlines import write_history_file
write_history_file('history.txt')
```

The exported file contains code from previous Python sessions also, while I am interested only in the code from the current session (in the snippet above this would be the first two commands).

Answer (score 0):

Using `[Doskey][1]/history` we can all previous command. **ONLY WORKS ON WINDOWS**. You can use readlines if you are using IPYTHON

```py
import subprocess

cmd_history = subprocess.check_output(["doskey", "/history"])
cmd_history_list = [line.strip() for line in cmd_history.decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
python_cmd_history = [line for line in cmd_history_list if line.startswith("python")]
print(python_cmd_history)
```